# OpenGL: How should 2D quads be stored/rendered?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, vbo

I store my model data in VBO/IBOs and render them using VAOs, which I understand is pretty much how it's normally done.

But I have non-model quads that are generated for 2D sprites and GUI, that consist of only 4 vertices.  The position of these quads is rarely the same (unless it's part of the GUI), and the UV coordinates change every frame as well.  Additionally, there are a large amount on screen at any one time, at least over a thousand.

I'm wondering, what is the best way to transmit single quads to the GPU and render them?

Assigning each a VBO feels like overkill, and clumping them into a single new VBO created/destroyed each frame, equally seems extreme.  But the only other way I could think of is to use Immediate Mode, which I've been avoiding since it's depreciated.

Comment: Why do you feel that using a VBO for each quad is "overkill"? You've got to get the data to the GPU somehow, and there really isn't any other way to do it. If it ends up being too slow, you'll have to switch to some other method, such as point sprites.

Comment: @AlchemicalApples - most guides I've read emphasis placing as much data as possible in a single VBO, so I just assumed they carried a lot of overhead.

Comment: Definetly use a single VBO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely put all your quads into a single vbo and draw just one when you want to. Having one vbo per rectangle is unnecessary overkill.